# MySQL : do I need indexes in this situation?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table 'Clients' and a sub-table 'Orders'.

For a certain view I need to display the *last* order for each client.

Since you cannot use LIMIT in a join, I first used a complex solution with a LEFT JOIN, GROUP_CONCAT and SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the last order, but this is quite slow, since there are millions of records.

Then I thought of just storing the last OrderID in the Clients table, that is updated by a trigger each time the Orders table changes. Then I just do a LEFT JOIN to Orders on this field LastOrderID.

Would an index on the field LastOrderID be of any use in this situation?  Or wouldn't it be used since the source table is always Clients, so there is no sorting, searching, etc. done on this field ?

The reason I'm asking is that in reality it's a little bit more complex, I might actually need about 20 of these kind of fields.

***update:***

My query now is :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Clients AS c 
LEFT JOIN Orders AS o ON o.OrderID=c.LastOrderID
```

Would an index on LastOrderID in Clients improve speed, or is it not neccessary?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do you have an index on the Client foreign key within the Order table?

Doing this alone should increase performance quite considerably.

Comment: I have a normal index on ClientID in Orders. I'm not using foreign keys though. Would this increase performance, or are foreign keys only important for data integrity ?

Comment: Not essential. Just checking you had the basics done, no index on the clientID in orders would be a scalability problem waiting to happen. I would recommend having the key on both ClientID then OrderNumber DESC, that way the server just has to check for the start of the clients block of orders, and take the first row it finds. Much fewer reads involved.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your SQL is wrong?

This is standard SQL: you'll need a single two column index on (ClientID, OrderID) on the Orders table for this which will speed up the aggregate and self join

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    (
    SELECT MAX(OrderID) AS LastOrderID, ClientID
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY ClientID
    ) o2
    JOIN
    Orders o ON o2.LastOrderID = o.ClientID AND o2.OrderID = o.ClientID
    JOIN
    Clients c PN o.ClientID = c.ClientID
```

Comment: I somehow don't like self-joins and complex group by's. My query is simply :   SELECT * FROM Clients AS c LEFT JOIN Orders AS o ON o.OrderID=c.LastOrderID

Comment: It is how you do an efficient "latest child per some parent" or "top 1 per group" in SQL. Other rdbms do it better but MySQL limits you